# href does not run properly

Tags: beamer, hyperref, external-files, adobe

I have been working with Mac and TeX Live, the newest version. I want to run videos by a mouse click on the PDF generated by a `beamer` presentation. I tried with shells and I also used `appify` to generate an app thereof. I also generated apps directly from the `AppscriptEditor`. However, when I click in Adobe, it complains that it can not find the application to run the underlying file as set by `\href` and `run`:

```
\href{run:./start.video100.app/Contents/MacOS/start.video100}{something}
```

I also tried relative paths... nothing is working.

Several users reported that they were successful in their cases. I want to start a script which then runs a playlist of videos, preferably in VLC. Can anybody help?

Comment: I know that Mac uses a different directive for folders. Instead of `/` it should be `:`. Read it somewhere, but now I can't find a reference.

Comment: Is you PDF viewer Mac OS's Preview? Sadly, it seems that Preview does not support hyperlinks. See [this](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1883602?start=0&tstart=0).

Comment: If you are under OSX and don't mind using adobe reader, try the `media9` package. Videos can be played in an embedded fashion, or in a detached player window.

Comment: @Werner That's pre-OS X: 'classic' Mac OS used a `:`, but OS X is Unix-based and uses `/`.

Comment: @AlexG Could you expand your comment here as an answer?

Comment: @AlexG Can you?

Answer (score 3):

[Converting AlexG's comment to an answer]

If you are under OS X and don't mind using Adobe Reader, try the `media9` package. Videos can be played in an embedded fashion, or in a detached player window.